# Android studio unable to download dependencies from maven google repository

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and trying to develop an app to use google map to track location. I followed instructions at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ak8uRvlpGS0 and created a google map activity project. 
Added following dependencies in app/build.gradle along with repo URL
app/build.gradle file

[image]

But, I am unable to download the dependencies and receiving the following error:

Dependency download error

[image]

I tried hitting the google central repo URL and received 404 and the link at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2151 also says that the URL can't be viewed.

Please help me to download dependencies so that I can remove all compile-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

try removing repositories tag from app gradle and place it in project level gradle

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though your suggestion helped remove the above error but I am now getting error as "Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3", which is a dependency added in app level gradle file

Comment: remove `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'`
and add this 
`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: I hope this helped you

Comment: Thanks . This indeed helped remove all the compilation errors and get all dependecies installed but when I run the app with following code:

Comment: Thanks. This indeed helped remove all the compilation errors but when I run the app with the following code:                                                                   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
      SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }  .I  get error as "cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(MapsActivity)" . Can you help?